# LookUp selected record not showing in related List

Tags: lookup, related-list, childrecords, relatedlistnew

I hope this is a good Monday for ya'll!

I have two objects, RFQ (master) and RFQ Lines (Children), I'm showing all related children on the master page using the Related List provided by the page builder.

Everything works fine, except for the fact that the lookup field in the children is not shown while simply viewing the Lines, but it is visible in the edit/new mode.

This is what I have in the page builder:
[image: This is what I have in the page builder]
[image: Those are the related settings]

This is what I see when looking at the records:
[image: View]

And this is what I see when I try to add a new record:
[image: New record]

Now my problem is that I need to see the results of the lookup in the list, right now it is just blank.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that `Scale Quantity` field is not populated on related list even if you have the lookup populated in edit mode on those records? The screenshot for records in the related list vs. the record in edit mode seems to be different. Do you have the lookup relationship established for the records that are currently part of the related list screenshot?

Comment: The records are actually populated correctly, but I need them to be shown to the final user even when not in edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two fields with the same name.
So the lookup that I saw in the edit was a different one with respect to the record view one.

I simply used the right lookup and everything showed up as expected.